# Exercise 4.3 from Rotman’s algebraic topology book , problem on singular Homology related to free Abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

For a given space $X$, define $S_1(X)$ to be the free *Abelian group* with basis all paths $\sigma : I \to X$, and let $S_0(X)$ be the free Abelian group with basis X.

Define $\delta_1 : S_1(X) \to S_0(X)$ with $\delta_1(\sigma)= \sigma(1) - \sigma(0)$ for every path $\sigma$ in $X.$

If $x_1, x_0 \in X$, show that $x_1 - x_0 \in im(\delta_1)$ iff $x_0, x_1$ lie in the same path component of X.

$\Leftarrow$ is trivial. I am stuck in showing how the direct implication follows rigorously. Geometrically I can see it but unable to write it down properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x_0$ and $x_1$ lie in different path components $X_0$ and $X_1$ respectively.
There is a group homomorphism $\phi:S_0(X)\to\Bbb Z$ which takes each
element of $X_0$ to $1$ and every other element to $0$. This map
$\phi$ takes each generator $\sigma(1)-\sigma(0)$ to zero, and so all of $\delta(S_1(X))$
to zero. But $\phi(x_1-x_0)=-1$, so $x_1-x_0\notin\delta(S_1(X))$
,

Comment: Actually $\phi$ sends all generators of $X_0$ to 1 and rest of the generators to 0. So, it takes each $\sigma(1) -\sigma(0) $ with the endpoints in $X-X_0$ to 0 and also paths with both the endpoints in $X_0$ are mapped to 0 so there will be a path joining one point of $X_0$ with one point of $X-X_0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is that forming the remainder of the proof?

Answer (score 0):

$x_1-x_0=\delta_1(\sigma)=\sigma(1)-\sigma(0)$ implies $\sigma(1)=x_1,\sigma(0)=x_0$ which proves the other hand, since $S_0(X)$ is the free Abelian group with basis X.

Comment: Yeah but there is a possibility that $x_1-x_0$ becomes image of a linear combination of paths in $S_1(X) $. In that case how should I proceed?

Comment: $x_1-x_0\in im(\delta_1)$ implies that there is a path $\sigma$ of X, such that $x_1-x_0=\delta_1(\sigma)$ holds.

Comment: No my question was that $S_1(X)$ is formed by $\Bbb Z$- linear combination of paths in $X$. So, is the assumption you made sufficient to deal with those cases?